# Extraer texto de variable considerando espacios y caracteres especiales

Tags: perl

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $body;
my $smtpCode;


$body = 'ESTO ES UN MENSAJE BUSCANDO EL CÓDIGO 550 5.1.1 y Nada más';

foreach ( split( /\n/, $body ) ) {
    next if (/^\s*$/);

    if ( $_ =~  /(\d{3}\s\d{1}\.\d{1}\.\d{1})/ig) {
        $smtpCode = $1;
        print $smtpCode;    # Mostrará: 550 5.1.1
    }
}
```

Pero ocurre que el texto `550 5.5.1`, en algunas ocasiones, llega como `550-5.1.1`, es decir, con un guión en vez de un espacio y quería saber si es posible hacer esa validación **sin** utilizar un `or`, es decir, que una función que tome en consideración cualquier carácter especial o espacio entre el 0 del 550 y el 5 del 5.1.1.

Obviamente los números también varían ya que el código está hecho para captar cualquier número que tenga esa estructura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es decir que entre el primer número y el segundo puede haber cualquier cosa que no sea un número, te vale con sustituir el primer "**\s**" por un "**\D**", que representa cualquier carácter que NO sea un dígito.

El código quedaría así:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $body = 'ESTO ES UN MENSAJE BUSCANDO EL CÓDIGO 550 5.1.1 y nada más';

my $smtpCode = "";

    for ( split( /\n/, $body ) ) {
        next if /^\s*$/;

        if (/\b(\d{3}\D\d\.\d\.\d)\b/) {
            $smtpCode = $1;
            print $smtpCode;
        }
    }
```

El modificador "**/g**" no lo necesitas porque la expresión no está en un bucle while(), y además solo estás buscando por el patrón por la línea, una sola vez. Tampoco necesitas el "**/i**" porque no hay comparaciones de tamaño de letra (mayúsculas/minúsculas).

Sí que se hace uso en el patrón de los límites de palabra, "**\b**", para asegurarnos que el código no forma parte de otro texto. Tampoco son necesarios los "**{1}**": con un "**\d**" es suficiente para indicar que buscamos por un dígito.

Comment: Gracias Joaquín, como siempre un crack en Perl!

Comment: Te esperamos en el foro de Perl en Español. Allí tienes muchas más respuestas.